# Component is not updating after async changing state

Tags: reactjs, async-await, settimeout, enzyme

In my app, I have a test like the one shown below, but after the click, the statement is not true, even if the manually tested behavior works:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

const Conceito = () => {
  const [alerta, setAlerta] = useState(false)

  const pesquisarOnClick = () => {
    setTimeout(() => setAlerta(true), 500)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      { alerta && <div data-component="Alerta">Mensagem</div> }
      <button
        action-trigger="pesquisar"
        onClick={pesquisarOnClick}
      >Pesquisar</button>
    </div>
  )
}

describe('<Conceito/>', () => {
  it('prova de conceito', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Conceito/>)
    expect(wrapper.find(`[data-component='Alerta']`)).toHaveLength(0)
    wrapper.find(`[action-trigger='pesquisar']`).simulate(`click`)
    await wrapper.update()
    expect(await wrapper.find(`[data-component='Alerta']`)).toHaveLength(1)
  })
})
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: ``` lang-js
import { render, fireEvent, waitForElement } from '@testing-library/react'

describe('<Conceito/>', () => {
  it('prova de conceito', async () => {
    const { container } = render(<Conceito />)
    expect(container.querySelector("[data-component='Alerta']")).toBeNull()
    fireEvent.click(container.querySelector("[action-trigger='pesquisar']"))
    expect(
      await waitForElement(() => container.querySelector("[data-component='Alerta']"))
    ).not.toBeNull()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Enzyme wrapper's functions `find` and `update` are synchronous, no need to resolve them as a promise using async/await. This also means that they are executed immediately, without waiting for your 500ms timeout.

If you need to specifically wait for these 500ms, you probably need to introduce some sort of wait function in your test:

```
function wait(miliseconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, miliseconds)
  })
}
```

and then `await wait(500)` (maybe more) before you `update` the component and assert your result

Comment: I understand that find and update are sync, but my result when 'pesquisar' has clicked, not. Because of this, I believe that I have to use async/await on test, to wait the promise (setTimeout) resolve and change the alerta state.

Comment: if `pesquisarOnClick`'s state setter is a result of a resolved promise, it doesn't change the fact that enzyme's functions are synchronous. Enzyme simply fires the onClick event and doesn't know that your handler is asynchronous and needs to be waited for.